# php-fpm workaround and Undefined index notices

Tags: header, logging

In implementing the php-fpm fix/workaround as detailed at:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/229253/#t383462

It results in "Undefined index: content-type" entries in the system.log for lines 107,114, and 123:

```
107: if ($sent[$name])
114: if (!is_null($existing = $headers[$name]))
123: if (!is_null($existing = $headersRaw[$name]))
```

Is there a cleaner way of implementing this fix to avoid these notices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use array_key_exists:

```
if (array_key_exists('$name', $sent))
```

You might want to combine it to check that the value isn't blank? So your 3 lines might be:

```
if (array_key_exists($name, $sent) && trim($sent[$name]) != "")
if (array_key_exists($name, $headers) && !is_null($existing = $headers[$name]))
if (array_key_exists($name, $headersRaw) && !is_null($existing = $headersRaw[$name]))
```